# Real Analysis Qualifying Exam Problem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

I think this should be an easy question, and I believe the answer should be in the positive, but I am not sure how to start.  I would appreciate some help.  Thank you.

> Suppose that $f_j$ is a sequence of functions in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ satisfying
>
> (i)  $\|f_j\|_\infty \leq 5$ and $f_j(x) = 0$ for $|x| \geq 10, j \in \mathbb{N}.$
>
> (ii) the $f_j$ converge pointwise to $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$.
>
> Does it follow that the $\hat{f_j}$ converge pointwise to $\hat{f}$?

Comment: Try applying the dominated convergence theorem with the uniform bound $|f_j(x)| \leq g(x)$ for $g(x) = 5 I_{(-10,10)}(x)$. Here $I_{(-10,10)}$ is the indicator function of the set $(-10,10)$. Also, I have a serious case of deja vu right now.

Comment: You went from asking "What is the derivative of $f(x) = 5 \cos (1.2 x)$?" to asking *this* in 1 hour!?!?!? Well done!

Comment: 'You' can be plural.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's enough to show that $\lVert f_n-f\rVert_{L^1}\to 0$.
2. In order to do that, we can use [Egoroff's theorem](http://planetmath.org/egorovstheorem): fix $\varepsilon>0$, and $S_\varepsilon\subset [0,1]$ such that $[-10,10]\setminus S$ has a measure $<\varepsilon$ and there is uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$ on $S$. Since all the $f_n$ and $f$ are supported by $[-10,10]$, we get
   $$\int_{\Bbb R}|f_n-f|d\lambda=\int_{[-10,10]}|f_n-f|d\lambda\leqslant 20\sup_{x\in S}|f_n(x)-f(x)|+10\varepsilon.$$